# Load dynamic Url's with Ajax/Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have searched through the web and cant find the solution to this problem. Ajax works great if the page I am loading is a static page, however, I cant seem to load dynamic urls with the same process. In the odd chance it works, it takes a long time to load the page.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').load('http://bookdem.com/se/index.php');

    //handle clicks 

    $('ul#nav li a').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load('http://bookdem.com/home/index.php?page=search&sPattern=&sCategory=1&sShowAs=list');
        return false;
    });
});
```

The code below works because its a static page in my directory. Cant seem to figure it out with dynamically created urls though.

```
$('#content').load('content2/'+page+'.php');
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav" class="nav-left">
    <li><a  href="about" >Textbooks</a></li>
    <li><a  href="contact" >Textbooks</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: show your html with <a> tag and `href` attribute

Comment: can you show your php script(the dynamic thing)..that would be of significant help in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't load cross-domain data out-of the box ([see here](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/cross_domain_aj)).

Here you can learn some [workarounds](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/calling-cross-domain-web-services-in-ajax/)... :-)

*N.B.: assuming bookdem.com is not your domain...*